# IRT models for repetitive items

Tags: psychometrics, item-response-theory, item-analysis

I'm looking for literature about IRT models that fit for tests in which items are presented for each examinee more than once and/or different questions are asked for the same item. For example, in the test the item "2+2" is shown twice, first when the examinee answers what is the equation sum and again when the examinee answers how many even numbers are in the equation. Or, in the test the examinee asked to rate for a picture valance and then asked to rate the picture's arousal (arousal and valence are orthogonal). Thus, the picture (the item) is shown twice but different aspects of the item are measured.

I'd be grateful for any direction and help.

Comment: But those are two different items.

Comment: I added another, maybe better, example

Comment: Would bifactor models be a solution to this?

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, I will check it out. Thank you @JeremyMiles!

Comment: I use the mirt package for bifactor models.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Jeremy Miles that the bifactor model$^1$ may be helpful for your situation, though I believe some additional clarity is needed. Generally speaking, the bifactor model falls within a larger class of latent variable models$^2$ characterized by one or more general (or primary) factors$^3$ and one or more orthogonal secondary (or nuance) factors. For instance, in your example:

> For example, in the test the item "2+2" is shown twice, first when the examinee answers what is the equation sum and again when the examinee answers how many even numbers are in the equation. Or, in the test the examinee asked to rate for a picture valance and then asked to rate the picture's arousal (arousal and valence are orthogonal). Thus, the picture (the item) is shown twice but different aspects of the item are measured.

an item could be responses to the "2+2" prompt corresponding to a particular picture. Such an item could be freed to load onto both the bifactor model's general factor, as well as an orthogonal secondary factor that only has items with the "2+2" prompt loaded onto it. Putting things like this$^4$, however, opens the question as to whether or not there should be a second set of secondary factors that are grouped by picture as opposed to prompt (e.g., "2+2", "3+3",...). Such a model would not technically be a bifactor model as items could load onto > 2 factors (i.e., one general factor and more than 1 secondary factor). Though both sets of secondary factors would still be orthogonal to the general factor, meaning the general factor could be interpreted similarly. To my knowledge, models with multiple sets of orthogonal factors are rare (though see Jeon, Rijmen, & Rabe-Hesketh, 2018 as a notable exception) though still possible to estimate as such a model is simply a multidimensional model with all correlations fixed to zero (with further restrictions). If you were to fit such a model in an item response theory (IRT) framework, I would recommend using the MH-RM (Cai 2010a; Cai 2010b) as the traditional Bock-Aitkin EM algorithm (Bock & Aitkin, 1981) may run into difficulties given the computational complexity of such a model$^5$.

$^1$ See Cai, Yang & Hansen (2011) and DeMars (2013) for more information on the bifactor model.

$^2$ Estimation of bifactor models using IRT full-information maximum likelihood was first proposed by Gibbons & Hedeker (1992), though one can also fit such models using factor analysis (FA)/structural equation modeling (SEM) methods as well (see Reise 2012 for more info).

$^3$ See Cai (2010c) for information on an extension to the bifactor model that allows for multiple (correlated) general factors.

$^4$ This gets to the point @Arya McCarthy made in the comments.

$^5$ Note that the Bock-Aitkin EM as implemented by software packages such as `flexMIRT` and the `R` package `mirt` is not computationally prohibitive thanks to dimension reduction (e.g., see Gibbons & Hedeker, 1992 for more info) though to my knowledge dimension reduction has not been extended for models where items may load onto > 1 secondary factor.

**References**

Bock, R. D., & Aitkin, M. (1981). Marginal maximum likelihood estimation of item parameters: Application of an EM algorithm. Psychometrika, 46(4), 443-459.

Cai, L. (2010). High-dimensional exploratory item factor analysis by a Metropolis–Hastings Robbins–Monro algorithm. Psychometrika, 75, 33-57.

Cai, L. (2010). Metropolis-Hastings Robbins-Monro algorithm for confirmatory item factor analysis. Journal of Educational and Behavioral Statistics, 35(3), 307-335.

Cai, L. (2010). A two-tier full-information item factor analysis model with applications. Psychometrika, 75(4), 581-612.

Cai, L., Yang, J. S., & Hansen, M. (2011). Generalized full-information item bifactor analysis. Psychological Methods, 16(3), 221.

DeMars, C. E. (2013). A tutorial on interpreting bifactor model scores. International Journal of Testing, 13(4), 354-378.

Gibbons, R. D., & Hedeker, D. R. (1992). Full-information item bifactor analysis. Psychometrika, 57(3), 423-436.

Jeon, M., Rijmen, F., & Rabe-Hesketh, S. (2018). CFA models with a general factor and multiple sets of secondary factors. Psychometrika, 83, 785-808.

Reise, S. P. (2012). The rediscovery of bifactor measurement models. Multivariate Behavioral Research, 47(5), 667-696.